# Div aparecer no bottom (Superscrollorama)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estou com um problema no Scrollorama. Gostaria que a div começasse a aparecer já no bottom, mas ela só está aparecendo quando já estou na metade do site.
A classe:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var controller = $.superscrollorama();
   var scrollDuration = 200; 
   controller.addTween('#fade', TweenMax.from( $('#fade'), .50, {css:{opacity:0}, ease:Quad.easeInOut}), scrollDuration);
});
```

Comment: É possível fazer um jsFiddle com um exemplo? ou dar um link para ver o problema live?

Comment: Eu usava essas classes do Greensock no Flash, em Action Script 3, nem sabia que tinham feito uma versão em Javascript! Como o Sergio mencionou, tente reproduzir o problema num [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), porque é muito difícil imaginar o que está acontecendo. Note que no jsfiddle existe uma aba "*External Resources*" onde é possível acrescentar bibliotecas externas, além do jQuery, então é possível fazer um exemplo funcional.

Comment: Coloca o HTML + Javascript aqui para vermos o que houve.

Answer (score 2):

Poderia tentar como no exemplo abaixo, apenas passando o posição via CSS.

```
controller.addTween(
    '#fade', 
    TweenMax.from( $('#fade'), .50, 
     { css:{opacity:0}, 
       css:{left: '0px'},
       css:{top: '0px'},
        ease:Quad.easeInOut
     } ), 
     scrollDuration );
```

Referência: http://www.princiweb.com.br/blog/front-end/ferramentas/o-tal-do-parallax.html